# How to design a depended object creation on runtime pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm currently facing a design problem:

- I want to design an application which has as user front-end and allows the user to add different "objects" on run time. These objects on the one hand may have impact on currently existing objects and on the other hand may be dependent on them.

E.g.: (Maybe a rather stupid example)

I have the objects `apple` and `cherry`, which have nothing to do with each other.
Now (on user request) the object `worm` is added, which causes apple to loose `flavor (apple.flavor = 0)` but increases apple.weight.
Cherry is not affected. Additionally, when `worm` is added but no `apple` exists, `worm.death = true`. It must also be considered, that "apple" may be removed later on, and the worm instance bound to this apple must "die" then.

Is there a design pattern to model such a structure? I have come across the visitor pattern
and dependency injection, but I'm not absolutely certain that these are the best possibilities.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a particular design pattern name that describes this, but it sounds like whenever your set of objects changes, you should pass the whole set to each of the objects to react to anything which is (or is not) contained in the set.

Comment: In your particular example, you may want to distinguish between active and inactive objects, where only the active objects react to the inactive (and possibly other active) objects in the set - your worm decreases the flavor of the apple, but the apple (especially not a non-existent apple) does not kill the worm; the worm dies because it cannot find any apple. Therefore, in your example, only the worm does something, be it to itself or to other objects. That may be worth a distinction in object type/treatment.

Comment: But removing an existing apple that has a worm bound to it should "kill" the worm. In this case apple becomes active, doesn't it?

Comment: That depends - if after removing the apple, the worm gets to re-examine the complete set of objects, and doesn't find its apple any more, it can still die on its own, without any activity on the part of the apple. Of course, the apple could alternatively call a *kill* method on any of its worms upon removal. Which solution is appropriate depends on what kinds of objects there are actually, which types can know about which other types (plugin system for additional objects, anywhere?) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the publisher/subscriber pattern. When an object dies or is created, its subscribers get a notification and execute some business logic.

Comment: Thought of this as well, but this would mean i have to implement a method "beEaten" on apple, where worm should have an "eat" method, doesn't it? (For when apple exists, when worm is created)

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Ant's eat method will call all of its listeners onAntEat method. Apple will implement an AntListener interface, and implement the onAntEat  method.